# Error en map en angular

Tags: angular

Obtengo error en la funcion map, para solucionarlo use la funcion pipe, pero me sigue saliendo error, no se como solucionarlo, que debo hacer?

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ListComponent } from './list.component';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable()
export class GithubService {
    private userName: string;
    private clientId: string = 'xxxx';
    private clientSecret: string = 'xxxx';

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
        this.userName = '';
    }

    getUser() {
        if (this.userName) {
            return this._http.get('http://google.com/' + this.userName
                + '?client_id=' + this.clientId
                + '&client_secret=' + this.clientSecret).pipe(
                .map(res => res.json()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu error? `res.json()` es innecesario con `HttpClient`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4/45129865#45129865

Comment: Por cierto, ¿esos credenciales son reales? Si es así bórralos cuanto antes

Comment: `map` es un *operador*. Le sobra el punto `'.'`.

Comment: @DavidSilva como soluciono el error en .json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sobra el punto del MAP te dejo el código y si las credenciales son reales eliminalas para que la gente no las vea.

```
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable()
export class GithubService {
    private userName: string;
    private clientId: string = 'xxxxxx';
    private clientSecret: string = 'xxxxxx';

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
        this.userName = '';
    }

    getUser() {
        if (this.userName) {
            return this._http.get('http://google.com/' + this.userName
                + '?client_id=' + this.clientId
                + '&client_secret=' + this.clientSecret).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: ahora obtengo el error en res.json

Comment: Necesitaría saber cuál es el error para poder ayudarte mejor y unos datos para poder replicar la petición que intentas hacer.